# Notepad++ dynamic "replace with"

Tags: replace, notepad++

I want to replace found result (with regular expression) by a dynamic space count.

This will be found by: `(XY\w.*_\d\d )(\w.*)`

```
XY_bbb_11 PT
XY_brtztsd_34 KJH
XY_bghg_44 LOP
```

Expected result:

```
XY_bbb_11       PT
XY_brtztsd_34   KJH
XY_bghg_44      LOP
```

Is it possible in Notepad++?

Comment: In Programmers' Notepad you could do Replace: `(XY\w.*_\d\d )(\w.*)` with `\1\t\2` to put a tab character between the 2 captures.  I don't think there's a way to put in a dynamic number of spaces using RegEx though.  I'm not familiar enough with Notepad++ to say whether it has anything on top of regex that may allow this; though I doubt it...

Comment: You could maybe fake it by doing a double replace; first replacing `(XY\w.*_\d\d )(\w.*)` with `\1  
                  \2` then replacing `^(.{10})(.*)(.{10})$` with `\1\3`... The right column would be right aligned rather than left aligned, and you'd need to know the max length of your 2 strings for each row to avoid accidental truncation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `Elastic TabStops` plugin.

1. Run plugin Manager and install Elastic Tabstops
2. Go to Plugins > Elastic Tabstops and tick `Enable`
3. tick Convert spaces to Elastic Tabs

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. The solution: "Convert Spaces to Elastic Tabs" and then "Convert Elastic Tabs to Spaces" 